# Cannot Authenticate AzureAD native client application

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have registered an AzureAD application which is a public client / Native Client.

I am using the standard code generated by Azure in the portal.

the important bits being

```
    static App()
    {
        _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
            .WithLogging((level, message, containsPii) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{level}: {message}");
            }, LogLevel.Verbose, true, true)
            .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
            .WithRedirectUri(RedirectURI)
            .Build();
        TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(_clientApp.UserTokenCache);
    }
```

and

```
         authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle) // optional, used to center the browser on the window
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```

The returned error is;

> "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter:
>   'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

Following what [I for example read here and in most places](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/08/receiving-error-aadsts7000218-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client_assertion-or-client_secret/) in AzureAD I have changed the default type to Public client.

I am still getting the same error.

I have enabled logging and I think i have the relevant part below

> Info: (False) MSAL 4.13.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0  (UnknownClient: 0.0.0.0) An authorization code was retrieved from the /authorize endpoint.
>   Info: (False) MSAL 4.13.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0  (UnknownClient: 0.0.0.0) Exchanging the auth code for tokens
>   Info: (False) MSAL 4.13.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0  (UnknownClient: 0.0.0.0) === InteractiveParameters Data ===
>   LoginHint provided: False
>   User provided: False
>   UseEmbeddedWebView: NotSpecified
>   ExtraScopesToConsent: 
>   Prompt: select_account
>   HasCustomWebUi: False
>
> Info: (False) MSAL 4.13.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0  (UnknownClient: 0.0.0.0) Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
>   Warning: (False) MSAL 4.13.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0  (UnknownClient: 0.0.0.0) Request retry failed.
>   Info: (False) MSAL 4.13.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0  (UnknownClient: 0.0.0.0) HttpStatusCode: 401: Unauthorized
>   Error: (True) MSAL 4.13.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0  (UnknownClient: 0.0.0.0) MSAL.Desktop.4.13.0.0.MsalServiceException: 
>       ErrorCode: invalid_client
>   Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

It appears I am getting a authorization code but failing to get the tokens. The error being 401 (Unauthorized).

Can someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: Not yet. I do  not administer the AzureAD so have to wait for an admin to get back to me.

Comment: I am getting back to this issue.  I am still getting the same error message.  I am honestly at a loss to know what to do.

Comment: I don't think so. If you already added Mobile and desktop applications platform, there will be some delay(a few minutes). If you still have a web platform, you can delete that and  try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two steps to fix this issue.

1.Change the default client type to Public client.

2.Add Mobile and desktop applications platform

[image]