# How to use the cmdlet Connect-PnPOnline with the options, ClientId, ClientSecret and AADDomain Options?

Tags: powershell, authentication, azure-ad-graph-api, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to use the command-let *Connect-PnPOnline* with the 3 options described in the question.

My aim is to create a MS Team team on my tenant and I need to connect to the function application, I guess
(which is going to run my PowerShell Script and the Graph API calls) to acheive this.

---

**Official Microsoft Documentation**

It's the 18th example of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps) pointing on this [other page](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Samples/Graph.ConnectUsingAppPermissions).

Unfortunetely the last link contains a lot of obsolete content.

---

**Errors**

- When I'am trying to execute this cmdlet inside a PowerShell terminal I'm not getting any error . I'm trying to get the connexion result into a variable but it contains nothing.

  `$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId '2994aca5-7bf4-4179-89ff-c1ce18fa052f' -ClientSecret 'secret' -AADDomain 'mydomain.com'`
- When I'am trying to execute this inside an actual PowerShell Script I'am getting this big stack (I have intentionnaly removed the method calls stack for readibility reasons)
  I'm getting the **SecretId** from my Azure account in Home -> Ressource Group -> myFunctionApp -> Function section - App Key -> default.
  I'm getting the **ClientId** from my Azure account in Home -> Azure ADD Active Directory -> App registrations -> myregistrationApp -> Application ID.

I do understand that the credentials are wrong but I dont know why.

- And finally FYI, the *configuration issue is preventing authentication* error have a [not-working-for-me] solution described on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868140/cannot-authenticate-azuread-native-client-application).

> MSAL.Desktop.4.17.0.0.MsalServiceException:
> ErrorCode: invalid_client

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details.You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.
> Trace ID: 31ee93b3-45b3-4058-9205-358e8e4da300
> Correlation ID: 4b4c139d-e21b-4b0e-96b4-89f4068cefe3
> Timestamp: 2020-08-13 16:54:54Z

> StatusCode: 401
> ResponseBody: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 31ee93b3-45b3-4058-9205-358e8e4da300\r\nCorrelation ID: 4b4c139d-e21b-4b0e-96b4-89f4068cefe3\r\nTimestamp: 2020-08-13 16:54:54Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2020-08-13 16:54:54Z","trace_id":"31ee93b3-45b3-4058-9205-358e8e4da300","correlation_id":"4b4c139d-e21b-4b0e-96b4-89f4068cefe3","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}
> Headers: Pragma: no-cache

> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> client-request-id: 4b4c139d-e21b-4b0e-96b4-89f4068cefe3
> x-ms-request-id: 31ee93b3-45b3-4058-9205-358e8e4da300
> x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.10922.14 - DUB2 ProdSlices
> x-ms-clitelem: 1,7000215,0,,
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
> P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
> Set-Cookie: fpc=Aulq_8y7IuJKshtSu9uJB4ocN4-WAQAAAF5nx9YOAAAA; expires=Sat, 12-Sep-2020 16:54:54 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None, x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
> Date: Thu, 13 Aug 2020 16:54:54 GMT

---

**Versions**

PowerShell: 5.1.18362.752

SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline: 3.24.2008.0

AzureAD: 2.0.2.106

Azure: 5.1.2

MicrosoftTeams: 1.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the wrong client secret.

In **Azure Active Directory** -> **App registrations** -> yourregistrationApp, to add a client secret:

- From the app **Overview** page, select the **Certificates & secrets**
  section.
- Select **New client secret**.
- Add a description for your client secret.
- Select a duration.
- Select **Add**.

After you save the configuration changes, the right-most column will contain the client secret value. **Be sure to copy the value** for use in your client application code as it's not accessible once you leave this page.

[image]